# Extending type with private constructor?

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I want to add some functionality to a type provided by a framework, but this type is a `singleton`.

Thus, it's **constructor is private**. My class is supposed to be `singleton` too, but I have no idea how to get it initialized. I cannot alter code of original class.

Now I do not extend, just keep a private property that gets initialized in my `getInstance`, and use __call(), but it's insufficient and not intuitive to use. I can't pass my objects where originall class is expected.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code that can demonstrate your question?

Comment: "My" base class is described at api.drupal.org and it's [down for me](http://drupal.org/node/2005804) so I cannot link you to it. My own code is nothing to look at, at the moment. Simple getInstance call and private property.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep the constructor in your extended class private. However, you could either do the following:

```
class originalClass
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        /* Do something */
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        self::__construct();
     }
}


class extendedClass extends originalClass
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        self::__construct();
    }
}

$var = extendedClass::init();
```

Alternatively, you could opt to have your class as a standalone, and use a magic method to access the 'parent' object:

```
class pdoExtender
{
    private $someProperty;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->someProperty = new PDO(...);
    }

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if(method_exists(array($this, $someProperty), $name))
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $someProperty), $args);
        }
    }
}

// Example function calls:
    $db = new pdoExtender;

    // As (obj)pdoExtender doesn't have the method 'prepare()', the __call() method is invoked to check the 'parent' object, PDO
    $db->prepare();
```

Comment: Original class is not editable for me. If I'm about to hack my framework, I can give up inheritance and just add my functionality directly - but I don't want to, I want to provide plugin, not a hack. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Using __call is ~ what I'm doing now. It has one big flaw - I cannot pass my object directly to functions that require base class. There is no way to define type casting, as php claims it's not needed. Thus, without real inheritance, I'm stuck

Comment: Why do you need to give up inheritance then? Could you not extend the class (even with a private constructor), and then use `__call()` to load the private constructor in your own class?

Comment: Maybe I can. the point is - I don't know HOW, to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, mis-understood! Let me add to my answer